# Is there any way to access hidden files android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file

I want to list files on this directory:
storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/
this is my code:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses");
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
```

There are 5 files in the directory, but `files.length()` returns 0. I guess it's because the Statuses Folder is `Hidden`.

When I tried this code for a normal folder it worked well, but it doesn't work for hidden folders. Can you help me?

Comment: No not because directory is hidden but because you use an Android 11 device.

Comment: If you are running on Android 11 or above, then no, not possible.
If you are running on Android 10 or below, it should be readable with appropriate permissions. For example, requestLegacyExternalStorage for Android 10 to allow you to read from other app's folders.