# How do I create a folder inside "Android/media" folder similar to whatsapp

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11

I want to create a folder inside "Android/media" folder like whatsapp does. Whatsapp is storing its media files inside "Android/media" folder. How do I achieve this?.
How can I create folder inside "Android/media"? .

Please don't mark it as duplicate or closed. I already looked through the solutions provided in the follwing similar questions. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem

1. [how to create folder inside /Android/media in android 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658332/how-to-create-folder-inside-android-media-in-android-11)
2. [Android 11 doesn't create app directory on external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044993/android-11-doesnt-create-app-directory-on-external-storage)

Comment: In your first link i told you how to do it. What did not work for you?

Comment: @blackapps First of all that's not my link.  Context:getExternalMediaDirs() is deprecated.

Comment: If whatsapp uses a deprecated function.. and you want to do it similar to whatsapp...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.